# « au dedans (de) » vs « en dedans (de) » vs « par dedans (de) »

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

D'après les pages 84, 85 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de 
Mary Crocker :

> au dedans = *inside, within*
>
> en dedans de = *inside*, *on the inside of*, *within*
>
> par dedans = *inside, through the inside*

En outre d'après le Wiktionnaire :

> [en dedans](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_dedans)
>   1. (Québec) à l’intérieur
>   2. (Québec) Dans un espace de temps
>   […]

Crocker n'affirme jamais que cette locution est québécoise.

Quels sont les points communs et les divergences ?

Au demeurant, peut-on ajouter « de » après toutes ces locutions adverbiales pour les relier à un nom ?

Comment: Lorsqu'on cite un ouvrage on ne change pas le contenu.

Answer (score 1):

De nombreux points de divergences existent entre le « français » et le « québécois » même s'ils sont tout deux regroupés sous l’appellation « francophonie ». Le contexte géographique des deux pays a amené à quelques changements dans la langue. On retrouve ce genre de changements entre l'anglais US et UK.

Pour ce qui est de cette expression "en dedans", elle n'a rien de québécoise puisqu'elle est une veille forme d'expression du français qui n'est plus utilisé en France mais que l'on peut retrouver dans des chansons ou textes anciens. Pour rappel, wikipédia est essentiellement basé sur sa communauté, ce n'est donc pas une source totalement fiable.

Pour ce qui est du "de" après une locution adverbiale, il faut que la liaison entraînée par le "de" ait un sens. Cela dépend donc de la locution adverbiale utilisée. Toutefois, cela reste une forme peu usitée dans le langage courant.

Comment: On peut aussi retourner l'argument *a contrario* et dire que la vigilance exercée par la communauté fait de Wikipedia une source beaucoup plus fiable et moins arbitraire que beaucoup d'autres.

Comment: Cet exemple est la preuve que non ^^ Wikipédia est un outil puissant certes, mais loin d'être infaillible. Même si la majorité de son information est vérifiée, une certaine partie est encore fausse. Par exemple certaines pages de célébrités où l'on a enlevé des faits "dérangeants", la page concernant Alésia, vrai selon les livres d'histoire scolaires mais qui a été prouvé comme fausse depuis plusieurs années. Un recoupement d'informations est TOUJOURS nécessaire sur internet. Pour ce qui est de notre cas, un dictionnaire produit par l'académie française me parait beaucoup plus approprié..

Comment: Je ne citais pas ton exemple en particulier mais ton jugement sur wikipedia. Quant à l'Académie Française c'est affaire de goût entre ceux qui veulent une langue vivante et colorée et les prescriptivistes.

Comment: C'est pour cela que je disais "n'est pas **totalement** fiable". Pour ce qui est de l'académie, je ne vais pas rentrer dans ce genre de débats stériles ^^ l'évolution d'une langue et son histoire sont deux choses **totalement** différentes.